# Copying data between two RedShift databases (from one to another) with AirFlow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, airflow

Can you help me with ideas on how I can copy data between two RedShift databases (from one to another) with AirFlow (these two databases stand on one cluster).

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do that with Airflow (unless you will implement a custom operator on your own).

A possible way is to export data from Redshift to S3 and then import from S3 to the 2nd redshift instance.

I didn't test it but this is the general idea:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.s3_to_redshift import S3ToRedshiftOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.transfers.redshift_to_s3 import RedshiftToS3Operator

S3_BUCKET = getenv("S3_BUCKET", "my-bucket")

my_dag = DAG(...)

op_transfer_redshift_to_s3 = RedshiftToS3Operator(
    schema="PUBLIC",
    table="my_table",
    s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
    unload_options=unload_options, #This is optional if you need to set options
    include_header=True,
    aws_conn_id="aws_conn_id",
    task_id="transfer_redshift_to_s3",
    table_as_file_name=True,
    dag=my_dag,
)

op_transfer_s3_to_redshift = S3ToRedshiftOperator(
    s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
    s3_key="my_table",
    schema="PUBLIC",
    table="my_table", #Or any other name you want in the 2nd Redshift
    copy_options=['csv'],
    aws_conn_id="aws_conn_id2", #Connection to the 2nd Redshift
    task_id='transfer_s3_to_redshift',
    dag=my_dag,
)

op_transfer_redshift_to_s3 >> op_transfer_s3_to_redshift
```

The `RedshiftToS3Operator` will be export my_table to in `s3://S3_BUCKET/my_table.csv` and `S3ToRedshiftOperator` will import from that path. You will need to overview the two operators to understand what kind of setup you need to use them

Comment: Thnx a lot. But maybe when I am trying to copy data between one schema I don't need to use S3?

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you are copying "data between two RedShift databases". What you are asking now isn't the same as your original question. If you want to do "in database" operations then you can use `PostgresOperator` to run `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Your first answer is very important for me because I can use it also. But I have my next question about copy data between different schemas into one database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687674/how-i-can-copy-data-from-one-scheme-to-another-one-in-redshift-with-airflow-with

Comment: Whats the value of "aws_conn_id2"? How to set it up? Can you please give an example? thanks

Comment: @Neo same way you set the first one. You just define a new Connection that refrense another account. See docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html