# How I can copy data from one scheme to another one in RedShift with AirFlow without S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-redshift, airflow

Can you help me create DAG for AWS Managed AirFlow to copy data from one scheme to another (there are in one database) in RedShift without an S3 bucket?

Thnx.

Comment: Is it scheme or schema? If schema, then its very simple, `insert into another_schema.table select * from mainschema.table` or multiple ways are there like create a stored procedure and put the source and target table names as parameters in airflow.

Comment: Yes, I mean "schema". Thnx for the advize. Don't understand "multiple ways are there like create a stored procedure and put the source and target table names as parameters in airflow". What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO {target_schema}.{table} select * from {source_schema}.{table}